# Input Validation & Return with either javascript or asp

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I need to know how to make a order look up validation.

For example if order number 2005 is entered into the field,
i want it to pull a specific html page.

If entered number is anything other than 2005 ,it will pull another html page.

Will be great if u guys can show for asp or java script with the .document write innerhtml for java script

how to do do this with javascript or asp?

Comment: What you want is `if (document.getElementById("someNumber").value == 2005) { document.write("2005") } else { document.write("not 2005") }` , or what?

Comment: no i want for example is variable x=2005, and someone types 2005 into input field...the javascript returns 2005.html.....if anything else...it returns else.html

Comment: Like [this](http://jsbin.com/babebugesi/1/)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can go about this. You can use JQuery or Javascript to make an AJAX request to validate the OrderNumber first. If Valid, that field gets posted back to the Form which envokes the response object to go to the page desired.

```
dim strOrderNumber
strOrderNumber = request("txtOrderNumber") ' Or whatever field name you gave this object

' Page gets posted and picks up here
if len(strOrderNumber) > 0 then
    ' Be sure to close any opened DB connections and destroy any objects that were created
    response.redirect("pagename_" & strOrderNumber & ".asp")
end if
```